# Using php null safe and null coalescing operators with an array containing anonymous functions

Tags: php, null-coalescing-operator

The following code works as expected:

```
$array = [];

// null
var_dump($array['foo']->bar ?? null);


// this throws a warning
var_dump($array['foo']?->bar);
```

The null-coalescing operator supports array while the null-safe operator doesn't.

--

Lets take the following code:

```
function calculate($num1, $num2, $action)
{
    $actions = [
        "add" => function ($a, $b) {
            return $a + $b;
        },
        "substract" => function ($a, $b) {
            return $a - $b;
        },
        "multiply" => function ($a, $b) {
            return $a * $b;
        },
        "divide" => function ($a, $b) {
            return $a / $b;
        }
    ];

    return $actions[$action]($num1, $num2) ?? "Action forbidden";
}

// 1) int(3)
var_dump(calculate(1, 2, 'add'));

// 2) Warning: Undefined array key "addd"...
var_dump(calculate(1, 2, 'addd'));
```

If I update the code with:

```
return $actions[$action] ?? "Action forbidden";
```

Then it works as expected:

```
// 3) string(16) "Action forbidden"
var_dump(calculate(1, 2, 'addd'));
```

Of course, if I update the code this way:

```
return array_key_exists($action, $actions) ? $actions[$action]($num1, $num2) : "Action forbidden";

// 4) string(16) "Action forbidden"
var_dump(calculate(1, 2, 'addd'));
```

But it loses all the benefits of null-coalescing...

**Question**

Why I cannot use null-coalescing with the following format (or what am I missing?):

```
return $actions[$action]($num1, $num2) ?? "Action forbidden";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is using the null-coalescing operator on the *result* of calling the function. So it won't prevent the undefined array index or calling the null function that results.

From the [Nullsafe Operator RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator#future_scope)

> **Future Scope**
> ...
> A nullsafe function call syntax ($callableOrNull?()) is also outside of scope for this RFC.

So this is something that may be addressed in the future, but it's not in the existing design.

Comment: Thanks! So the best practice in my case is to use `return array_key_exists($action, $actions) ? $actions[$action]($num1, $num2) : "Action forbidden";`?